# how to extract high frequency phrase in python

Tags: python, frequency, frequency-analysis, word-frequency

This is the corpus

```
abcdef
abcd
xabcd
b
bcef
ef
aef
```

what I want to extract is `abcd`, `ef`, then I try to count all n-grams:

```
abcdef 1
abcd 3
abc 3
...
```

My question is how to distinguish `abcd` with `abcdef` and `abc`, since `abcdef` just appear once, and `abc` is the sub-string of 'abcd'. Of course, I can filter with this two conditions, but just want to know any existing algorithm target on solving this problem, or a package in python?

### UPDATE

I DO know how to count n-gram in python, so my question is more about how to distinguish `abcd` with `abcdef` and `abc` not how to count. But if you know any python package that target on solving this NLP problem, good to know:)

Comment: so `a` is consider a word, as well as `abc` and `abcd`?

Comment: @Mai, the short answer is yes. But in the corpus, `a` appear 4 times, 3 times in `abcd`, so I don't want to extract it, since most likely, it's a part of a high frequency phrase `abcd`

Comment: I think this is quite a hard problem in NLP. I don't see a clear definition of a phrase in your question, though I sort of see what you want. Maybe what you want is *the longest phrase* among strings that (1) completely covers some substrings (2) happens at least N times.

Comment: I use scikit-learn for this type of operation, their CountVectorizer does character n-grams too http://scikit-learn.org/stable/tutorial/text_analytics/working_with_text_data.html

Comment: @Mai exactly it's a hard problem in NLP, and I can only use word frequency to define what's the phrase. Anyway, `No answer` is also an answer to me, thanks a lot!

Comment: @YuwenYan - did my answer below not address the question?

Comment: @Boa thanks for your answer, I just updated my question. It's a problem in NLP area, not how to count n-gram in python. Sorry for confusing.

Answer (score 0):

Consider letters in this question as tags of POS. This can be considered a Grammar Extraction problem, given sentences already parsed into POS.

I am not sure if `NLTK` or other libraries in `Python` deals with this problem. But I do think you can search for literature and implement a simple extraction on your own.

Hope this helps.